# LDAP userAccountControl atttribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

In `PowerShell` I use the following `LDAP query` to retrieve the active directory properties of a host name:

```
$Filter = "(&(ObjectCategory=Computer)(ObjectClass=Computer)(CN=$ComputerName))"
if ($Found = ([ADSISEARCHER]$Filter).FindOne()) {
    $Details = $Found.GetDirectoryEntry()
}
```

Once I have these properties I would like to check if the computer account is disabled. The following `LDAP query` is allowing me to do that:

```
$Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(CN=$ComputerName))"
([ADSISEARCHER]$Filter).FindOne()
```

What I would like to know is, how can I avoid using the second `LDAP query` and use the variable `$Details` from the first `LDAP query` to obtain `$True` or `$False` if the computer account is disabled?

I found some [extra information](https://knowledge.zomers.eu/PowerShell/Pages/How-to-control-UserAccountControl-Active-Directory-flags-with-PowerShell.aspx) but I can't seem to put the pieces together.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it required to use LDAP queries or you may also use ActiveDirectory module in powershell?

Comment: No, the `ActiveDirectory` isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you're looking for is encoded in the `userAccountControl` of the directory entry object. However, the property contains an array with a numeric value, so you need to check if the "disabled" [flag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305144) (numeric value 2) in the first array element is set:

```
$disabled = [bool]($Details.userAccountControl[0] -band 2)
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. When I try it on a computer account name that is `Enabled` I get `FALSE` and when I try it on a `Disabled` one I get `FALSE` to.

Comment: Can't reproduce. If I use the above on a disabled computer I get `$true`. If the computer is enabled I get `$false`. What's the output of `$Details | fl *` for a computer where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: It was an error in my testing process. You are correct, this works perfectly! Thank you for your help.